# view counter update in WordPress REST api HTTP get

Tags: rest-api, views, wp-remote-request

I use WordPress rest API for app communication with my site in need update post view counter when HTTP get API.

I search a lot but nothing found about it, in a tutorial "Find popular posts with the WordPress REST API" view counter update when call HTTP get API URL but it's in custom endpoint but I need this update function in rest API default endpoint

the code for popular post custom endpoint :

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'base', '/views/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'post_view_counter_function',
  ));
});
function post_view_counter_function( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
  $post_id = $request['id'];
if ( FALSE === get_post_status( $post_id ) ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'error_no_post', 'Not a post id', array( 'status' => 404 ) );
  } else {
    $current_views = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'views', true );
    $views = $current_views + 1;
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'views', $views );
    return $views;
  }
}
```

how I change and use for my purpose?

in default get rest API URL is: `"http://www.test.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/id".` there is a custom field for view counter. when using Get Request rest API URL of a post, view field increase

thank a million

Comment: what doesn't work with this code ?

Comment: it's create a new endpoint that increase view counter by every html get request

https://medium.com/fiatinsight/find-popular-posts-with-the-wordpress-rest-api-109013bdc5e3

Comment: ok I understand now. to add this modification on default endpoints, read this : https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/